# importing script in python terminal

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to import a python script file into terminal (invalid syntax)

Hi, I am trying to import a python script file in my python terminal however a is giving me an error when the script name starts with a number or includes certain characters like `_` (I am still a beginner)

This works fine:

```
>>> import a00
 Bright Green
```

However this give me invalid syntax:

```
>>> import 00a
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import 00a
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or this

```
>>> import 00_a
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import 00_a
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python module (meaning a .py file) names follow the same naming rules as variables, so they can only start with underscore or a letter. After the first character, you can use numbers also.

(Dashes are also technically allowed, but should be avoided since using them requires special syntax.)

The preferable convention for module names is to have them be all lowercase characters, and underscores if needed.

You can read more from the [Python PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, names cannot begin with digits, so any name like `0abcd` or `1nfi`, but not `a00`, will be invalid.